# Two way SSL X509 Certificate location for secure service request in .Net Core MVC - Azure Services Hosted application

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, openssl, ssl-certificate

I've being working with x509 certificates in order to make secure requests to some data services. They require Two way SSL auth, so I've converted my "Sandbox" certificate (.crt) w/ my Private Key to a Password protected .p12 file.

Here's the first question: Where should I place this .p12 file so that it's readable by my application after deploying to Azure (Using DevOps) but still stored securely? Can I use an my Azure Key Vault?

The second issue is that in my Dev environment I haven't been able to establish the SSL binding after making the request (With a .p12 absolute path):

Here's the code I'm using:

```
void GetATMs()
    {
        string requestURL = "https://sandbox.api.visa.com/globalatmlocator/v1/localatms/atmsinquiry";
        string userId = "MyUserId";
        string password = "MyPassword";
        string p12certificatePath = "C:\\Code\\projects\\project\\\\Clients\\PaymentGateways\\Visa\\Certs\\TC_keyAndCertBundle.p12";
        string p12certificatePassword = "CertPassword";
        string postData = @"{""wsRequestHeaderV2"": { ""requestTs"": ""2018-11-06T03:16:18.000Z"", ""applicationId"": ""VATMLOC"", ""requestMessageId"": ""ICE01-001"", ""userId"": ""CDISIUserID"", ""userBid"": ""10000108"", ""correlationId"": ""909420141104053819418"" }, ""requestData"": { ""culture"": ""en-US"", ""distance"": ""20"", ""distanceUnit"": ""mi"", ""metaDataOptions"": 0, ""location"": { ""address"": null, ""placeName"": ""700 Arch St, Pittsburgh, PA 15212"", ""geocodes"": null }, ""options"": { ""range"": { ""start"": 10, ""count"": 20 }, ""sort"": { ""primary"": ""city"", ""direction"": ""asc"" }, ""operationName"": ""or"", ""findFilters"": [ { ""filterName"": ""OPER_HRS"", ""filterValue"": ""C"" } ], ""useFirstAmbiguous"": true } } }";

        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestURL) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "POST";
        // Add headers
        string authString = userId + ":" + password;
        var authStringBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authString);
        string authHeaderString = Convert.ToBase64String(authStringBytes);
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authHeaderString;
        // Add certificate
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(p12certificatePath, p12certificatePassword);

        request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        // Get the request stream.  
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        // Write the data to the request stream.  
        dataStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        // Close the Stream object.  
        dataStream.Close();
        // Get the response.  
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        // Display the status.  
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.  
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.  
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        // Read the content.  
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // Display the content.  
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        // Clean up the streams.  
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
```

What am I missing here?

It fails the following way:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
Win32Exception: The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized
System.Net.SSPIWrapper.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SSPIInterface secModule, string package, CredentialUse intent, SCHANNEL_CRED scc)

HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

WebException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

We have a Wildcard SSL for our domain. Are they different? Can it be registered in the Visa dashboard and used for make secure request as it is signed by a trusted CA authority?

Comment: According to your error , it seems the csr is not correctly created . Please read the doc: https://developer.visa.com/pages/working-with-visa-apis/two-way-ssl#configuring_twoway_ssl_keystore_using_your_own_csr and follow the steps if using your own csr.

Comment: But I've being working with those same credentials through SoapUI successfully so I've realized It isn't an authentication problem.

Comment: @DanielLozano I have the same problem, Did you find a solution?

Comment: @dagope Not yet, but it seems that the certificates are not being setted up to be consumed by our application. https://codeopinion.com/asp-net-core-csproj-embedded-resources/ check this out. Might be the solution we are looking for

Comment: thanks @DanielLozano, Finally I found solution creating a .pfx file with openssl tool, then I upload it like Private Certificate in the SSL Configuration Azure.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes. As per, @dagope Recommendation, I've uploaded my certificate to key-management on Azure and access it through the SDK. This is also a best practice for key/certificate management on Azure.